# Ошибка при выполнение react-scripts build

Tags: reactjs, build

При билде react приложения, хочу вызвать `INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false npm run build`  для того, чтобы избежать вызова inline функций, но получаю следующий exception:

`INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false : Имя "INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.`

Comment: В какой ОС это делается?

Comment: Выполняется в Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для Windows cmd.exe необходимо выполнить

```
set "INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false" && npm run build"
```

Подробнее для остальных OS:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-temporary-environment-variables-in-your-shell